# ListAdapter does not display information

Tags: java, android, json

Can someone help me with this problem?. Can't get the string of "lugar" in my ListView. I don't know what I did wrong :(

I'm new here and also in developing android apps.

Recently opened a question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840052/why-the-result-always-be-null-while-parsing-json-java

That problem is solved but I have a new. :(

**Java Code:**

```
private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

        private ProgressDialog pDialog;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Espere...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();
            JSONObject json;

            // Getting JSON from URL
            json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://example.com/myjson.json");

            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

            pDialog.dismiss();

            if(json != null) {

                try {
                    // obtener arrays
                    JsonArr = json.getJSONArray("json");

                    for (int i = 0; i < JsonArr.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject c = JsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                        String lugar = c.getString("lugar");

                        // Adding value HashMap key => value
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put("lugar", lugar);

                        oslist.add(map);

                        list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lista);

                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), oslist,
                                R.layout.list_item,
                                new String[]{lugar}, new int[]{
                                R.id.nombre});
                        list.setAdapter(adapter);
                        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You Clicked at " + oslist.get(+position).get("lugar"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });


                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "json: null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

**lista_medios.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lista"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/abc_list_item_padding_horizontal_material">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nombre"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: @Beat Sorry (I have already modified)

Comment: are you actually using http://example.com/myjson.json or is that dummy address? Give us a real one

Comment: I did not use this url in my real code (only for publication). My json code is this: `{"json":[{"lugar":"lugar 1","lista":[{"id":"1","nombre":"nombre 1"},{"id":"2","nombre":"nombre 2"}]}]}` and I can get the information. For Example: In my application when I click on an item , I see ( toast ) the obtained information, but not within the item (TextView) :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this:

```
String[] from = new String[]{ "lugar" };
int[] to = new int[]{ R.id.nombre };

ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,
                                R.layout.list_item,
                                from, to);
```

The from clause should contains the name of your columns, in this case the key in HashMap.